# Событие до обработки метода web-службы (svc)

Tags: asp.net, .net

Здравствуйте.
Есть ли какое-нибудь событие до обработки метода web-службы (svc)?
Web-служба у меня - Singleton.
Мне нужно настроить некоторые настройки перед тем, как будет метод выполняться.
Вставлять вызов метода настройки в каждый метод web-службы - это как-то нехорошо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если Singleton, то в конструкторе службы. Или при старте хоста.

Comment: Вот, например, мне нужно установить культуру `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` текущего юзера, а потом только выполнить метод, а при стартапе или в конструкторе это выполнится только один раз...

Comment: В WCF я для этого добавляю инспектора, у которого перекрыты методы AfterRecieveRequest и BeforeSendReply. А в методе AfterRecieveRequest делаю что надо с текущим потоком.